# Main function complains of returning a non IO monad

Tags: haskell

```
import Debug.Trace

main = do
  trace "Main function parses, and returns - " "0"
  return ()
```

This throws error as,

```
app.hs:3:1:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘[()]’
    In the expression: main
    When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
```

If i am not wrong, the module must work without return. But with or without return function, it is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`trace` isn't an IO action! Its type is:

```
trace :: String -> a -> a
```

so the compiler infers that you're defining `main` to be in the *List monad*! Hence it complains that you're defining it as a `[()]` when it should be `IO ()`.

Try using `traceIO` (or simply `putStrLn`) instead. Keep in mind that `trace` is a debugging function: it prints things unsafely and "breaks out" of the IO monad, which a real, working program should never ever do.

(In general, you can avoid confusion by writing the type signatures yourself: always write your `main` function as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  ...
```

and then the error you get will be less confusing, as GHC won't infer a weird type.)

Answer (score 8):

Since your `trace` line returns a list (the string "0", which is of type `[Char]`), you're actually invoking the list monad, not the IO monad.  The `return` function for the list monad makes a single-element list from its argument:  in this case, `[()]`.

Change the second argument of `trace` to be an IO action instead of a list.