# Haskell treats multiple lines of code as a single function call

Tags: haskell

```
pure :: String -> ()
pure x = unsafePerformIO $ do
  print x
  return ()

pureCall :: String -> IO ()
pureCall x = do
  pure x
  putStrLn "inside child function"
```

This throws compilation error as,

```
  The function ‘pure’ is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ‘String -> ()’ has only one
```

I use semicolon as code line seperator in other languages. But not sure, how i can do it in haskell, and run the pureCall function block as two seperate statements!!

Comment: You have `pure x :: ()` in an IO monad `do` block. Every action in such a block should have type `IO t`.

Comment: Is your problem maybe resolved by simply removing the `unsafePerformIO` call?

Comment: hi Mauris, updated my question after your inputs..

Comment: Two extra remarks, even though you are probably aware of them already, and even though your code is just a test: firstly, there is a very common function called `pure`, so it is not a good name to use (in the latest GHC, you would get a name clash even without importing anything). Secondly, *stay away from `unsafePerformIO`* - it really is unsafe!

Comment: As for the edited question, the issue is the same than in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580302/main-function-complains-of-returning-a-non-io-monad): you are ignoring the types. `IO ()` is not the same thing than `()`.

Comment: **Do not change your question**. If you have a different (even if related question) ask a **new** question and eventually link to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're indenting the `pure` and `putStrLn` lines identically (so don't do one using tabs and the other with spaces). If ghc thinks `putStrLn` is indented further, then it will be considered as arguments to `pure`.

If you want, you can use semicolons in Haskell too:

```hs
pureCall :: String -> IO ()
pureCall x = do {
  pure x ;
      putStrLn "inside child function"
  }
```

works as you'd expect.

(Also note that your code is not well typed: `pure` is not of type `IO a`.)